# How can I give dynamically unique ID to a table's rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[SOLVED] Description can be found on the bottom.

I got stucked while trying to handle dynamic IDs in a dynamically created table's rows. I already solved how to upload these dynamic datas into MySQL database with PHP. Could you help me, please?

I have a static table header and a static first row and the user can add dynamically rows.

**Here is my simplified html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> first </th>
        <th> second </th>
        <th> third </th>
        <th> fourth </th>
        <th> fifth </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td><select (need an onchange="something()" here) name="product_name[]"> <option>listed by php from sql</option>
            <td ><p> Here comes the UNIT depending on the first cell of the row</p></td>
            <td> other input fields ... </td>
            <td>button which adds a new row, cloneing the last row's style</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**And my javascript:**

```
function addRow(tableID, o) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.id = parseInt(table.rows[rowCount-1].id)+parseInt(1);
    var colCount = table.rows[rowCount-1].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[rowCount-1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
    o.style.display = "none";

    var x = document.getElementsByName()
}
```

The question is..

How is it possible, when a user changes a row's  element's value, the same row's other cell get changed.
I used AJAX until I had to make the table dynamic, but now I have no clue how to continue. I just need a little snippet or hint, because I have totally don't know how to give dynamically ids to the given cell in each row and then how to handle it. I need some solution like I did it in PHP (processing the table's inputs):

**Working PHP code:**

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $cname = $_POST['customer_name'];
    $place = $_POST['product_place'];
    $date = $_POST['product_date'];
    $cassa = $_POST['customer_cassa']; 
    $name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $amount = $_POST['product_price'];
    $price = $_POST['product_price'];

    foreach($name as $a => $b){ 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bevetelezes (vasarlo, helyszin, datum2, termek, mennyiseg, kassza) VALUES ('$cname', '$place', '$date', '$name[$a]', '$amount[$a]', '$cassa') ";
        if ($r = $conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
```

Thank you so much for your reply in advance!
Best regards,
Zoltan

---

Description: 
Okay, I solved it myself, it was easier than I thought. Here is the solution if anyone is interested in it:

Inside my table:

```
<select onchange="get_unit(this.value, this)" required="required" name="t_neve[]">
```

The javascript function which searches for the classname unit inside the given row and calls the unit from
database and writes it.

```
function get_unit(str, object) {

          var row = object.parentNode.parentNode;
          var a = row.getElementsByClassName("unit");
          var x = a[0];

          var xhttp;    
          if (str == "") {
              x.innerHTML = '<p class="text-left">----</p>';
            return;
          }
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              x.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_ujbevetel.php?q="+str, true);
          xhttp.send();

      }
```

And the cell that the ajax modified:

```
<td width="65%">
    <div class="unit">
    <p class="text-left">----</p>
    </div>
/td>
```

Comment: Try editing you question, im atleas, having a hard time understanding what you want to actually do. Where do you submit your post.  And is addRow working, cuz you want to give the rows dynamic ids, but isnt that what addRow is doing?

Comment: While I also think you need to clarify your question, I'm also curious as to why each `<tr>` and, apparently `<td>` needs an `id`; what are you doing that targets dynamically-created elements by its `id`?

Comment: "My question is, How is it possible, when a user changes a row's element's value (in <select>), the same row's other cell get changed. I used AJAX until I had to make the table dynamic, but now I have no clue how to continue. I just need a little snippet or hint, because I have totally don't know how to give dynamically ids to the given cell in each row and then how to handle it. I need some solution like I did it in PHP (processing the table's inputs)"

Comment: Okay, I solved it myself, it was easier than I thought. Here is the solution if anyone is interested in it:
Inside my table:
<select onchange="get_unit(this.value, this)" required="required" name="t_neve[]">
The javascript function which searches for the classname unit inside the given row and calls the unit from
database and writes it.

Comment: I don't know, how could I add a code to here?  -sorry

Comment: Please answer your own question by posting it as an answer below. You can accept your self-answer after 48 hours.